# Why does gethostbyname() intermittently give HOST_NOT_FOUND for hostname?

Tags: c++, macos, osx-elcapitan, hostname, gethostbyname

On Mac OS X El Capitan, I am running a C++ application that calls `gethostbyname()` and sometimes passes the argument string matching the current machine:

```
bash-3.2$ hostname
Ws-MacBook-Pro
```

This normally works, however, on rare occasions, I get a `NULL` result and `h_errno` is set to `HOST_NOT_FOUND`.

Is this a known issue?  How can my application recover from this?  I'd like to retry on the hopes it succeeds, but how would I distinguish a real host not found failure from this transient one for the current machine's name?  How long would such a failure likely persist and what might be causing it?

Comment: have you tried printing the value passed to gethostbyname() when you get a null to make absolutely sure it's not a bad argument?

Comment: @kfsone Yes, my error message printed the value and showed it was not corrupted.

Comment: The usual reason is a flaky/unreachable DNS server.

Comment: Have you tested this with the [loopback address](http://superuser.com/questions/255835/whats-a-loopback-address-i-e-127-0-0-1) to see if your NIC has an issue? If it passes with a zero failures, it is likely a flaky DNS server as @SamVarshavchik pointed out. Otherwise there is some fault in your local machine's hardware. Do you know what protocol `gethostbyname()` is using?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The local hostname shouldn't even be in DNS.

Comment: @barmar - gethostbyname() looks up any name in DNS. Even local hostname's.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How would your local hostname get into the public DNS? There isn't even a domain suffix on it. OS X actually uses mDNS, which consults a local database first before going to the real DNS server.

Comment: @Barmar - who said anything about public DNS? If the OP is on a corporate network or a LAN, the local DNS servers will be authoritative for the zone.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Who said anything about a corporate network? Absent anything in the question about a local DNS server, I'll assume it's a personal Macintosh using his ISP's DNS (or something like Google DNS).

Comment: @Barmar Yes, using ISP's DNS.

Comment: You really should stop using `gethostbyname()` altogether, use `getaddrinfo()` instead. If you want the address(es) of the local host, use `getifaddrs()` instead.